# database query error unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to show some data from much table but got some errors with my query, still have no idea where to fix it this is my query

```
SELECT stok.harga_jual, 
produk.nama_produk, 
produk.idkategori, 
produk.deskripsi, 
produk.foto, 
pengiriman.nama, 
pengiriman.alamat, 
pengiriman.kodepos, 
pengiriman.id_kota, 
delivery.nama AS shipment, 
delivery.harga AS biaya_pengiriman, 
transaksi.jumlah, 
transaksi.noinvoice FROM transaksi RIGHT OUTER JOIN produk ON transaksi.idproduk = produk.idproduk
 LEFT OUTER JOIN pengiriman ON pengiriman.noinvoice = transaksi.noinvoice
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN delivery ON delivery.id_delivery = pengiriman.id_delivery
 LEFT OUTER JOIN stok ON stok.idproduk = produk.idproduk WHERE transaksi.noinvoice = E0001
```

with that i got some error like

## 1054 - Unknown column 'E00001' in 'where clause'

Comment: is transaksi.noinvoice a text field? In which case E0001 would need to read 'E0001' other than that we would need to know more about the database structure

Comment: transaksi.noinvoice is varchar(6) 
i got confused with my database structure if you can tell me what i have to show you some data.

Comment: E0001 is the problem, its column here...  'E0001' is a value.

Comment: @Andi Check my answer, I hope It should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you missing `''` on `E0001` value. Should be `'E0001'`

Full code:

```
SELECT stok.harga_jual, 
produk.nama_produk, 
produk.idkategori, 
produk.deskripsi, 
produk.foto, 
pengiriman.nama, 
pengiriman.alamat, 
pengiriman.kodepos, 
pengiriman.id_kota, 
delivery.nama AS shipment, 
delivery.harga AS biaya_pengiriman, 
transaksi.jumlah, 
transaksi.noinvoice FROM transaksi RIGHT OUTER JOIN produk ON transaksi.idproduk = produk.idproduk
 LEFT OUTER JOIN pengiriman ON pengiriman.noinvoice = transaksi.noinvoice
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN delivery ON delivery.id_delivery = pengiriman.id_delivery
 LEFT OUTER JOIN stok ON stok.idproduk = produk.idproduk WHERE transaksi.noinvoice = 'E0001'
```

Comment: oh yes i've miss that.. may i'm tired doing this get some sleep first.. thaks for your help .

Comment: Your welcome, do not forget to accept It as correct answer. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT stok.harga_jual, 
       produk.nama_produk, 
       produk.idkategori, 
       produk.deskripsi, 
       produk.foto, 
       pengiriman.nama, 
       pengiriman.alamat, 
       pengiriman.kodepos, 
       pengiriman.id_kota, 
       delivery.nama AS shipment, 
       delivery.harga AS biaya_pengiriman, 
       transaksi.jumlah, 
       transaksi.noinvoice
FROM transaksi
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN produk ON transaksi.idproduk = produk.idproduk
                          AND transaksi.noinvoice = 'E0001'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pengiriman ON pengiriman.noinvoice = transaksi.noinvoice
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN delivery ON delivery.id_delivery = pengiriman.id_delivery
  LEFT OUTER JOIN stok ON stok.idproduk = produk.idproduk
```

Note how I've moved the `WHERE transaksi.noinvoice = 'E0001'` condition to the `ON` clause. (If you have outer table conditions like this in the `WHERE` clause, that `OUTER JOIN` executes as a regular `INNER JOIN`!)